Pinout of Philips P2000 "composite" output
I got my hands on a Philips P2000 home computer (no T, C or M) and the back only has these connections:

I understand that the DIN-6 is actually a composite output, but I can nowhere find a pinout for these. I just connected the cable (I have one laying around from my C64) to a SCART, but no result (I only got a black screen with a white bar on the right).
I have no experience at all with these machines, so I don't even know if this one works, and if it does, how I can find it out. Most online resources talk about a P2000T, with different outputs.

For the uninitiated - what's a P2000?

I've never even heard of a P2000, but I guess you could try figuring out which of those pins are tied to ground and probe the remaining pins with an oscilloscope to see what they look like.

Can you please add that the P2000 is a home computer made by Philips for European market?

Partial answer:
To my understanding, there was no "bare" P2000, it's either a T, a M, or a C.
The back side of the model T looks like yours, except the two lower video ports are open. The left one (with the 3 dots) is a DIN-6 with RGB signals, the right one is a coaxial HF-modulated connector for a TV.
I couldn't find an image for the model M, but it's reasonable to assume that the video icon with no 3 dots means monochrome video, so you could have a model M. Potentially you can verify this by opening up the computer; it should have an extra card to produce 80-column monochrome output. If the video output comes from this card, and if the main card video generation is unpopulated, then you have a model M.
A manual for both the T and the M version can be found here. Section 3.8.10 on page 3-32 lists five signals, namely



Pin
Signal




1
L


2
L


3
Vert. Sync


4
Video


5
Horiz. Sync



The connector visible in your picture also seems to have 5 signals. The DIN connector wikipedia page has the standard pinout numberings.
I am not entirely sure what L is, but I've seen L and H in the other diagrams, and potentially they are other names for GND (Low) and +5V (High), though I don't understand why there are two sets of names. They use NC for not connected, and GND for Ground in other places.
If you have access to a scope, identifying the signals should be easy. Otherwise compare the cabling on the inside with the manual.
If you get white bar on the right when mapping pins in the wrong way to SCART, that means the whole thing works and actually produces output.

It is a "bare" P2000. The front says "P2000", no "T" attached. I read they were only used  "internally", I reckon Philips then.

"If you get white bar on the right when mapping pins in the wrong way to SCART, that means the whole thing works and actually produces output." -- That's great news and gives hope for further research ;-). Thanks a lot!

@BartFriederichs then the next step is definitely to open it up, see what boards you have, see how they are connected. If it's a custom Philips-internal model, of course it may not match any public information, so you'll have to do some sleuthing, anyway.

"L" could be Luminance. Just a guess. But alas, where's the needed GND then?

I think they use L instead of GND in other places too. Someone with more insight to language of the country it was designed in may offer confirmation.

@justme On second thought, "Luminance" doesn't make sense. They seem to be using "L" for GND in other places as well. Maybe it's simply abbreviating "LOW" - For "logic ground".

@BartFriederichs This forum post has an image of a P2000T (identified as model T by the owner, you can also see the cabinet with monitor and floppies) that is just labelled "P2000". So I guess these were not that uncommon...

@dirkt Apparently. I opened it up yesterday (checking power, etc) and found two extension boards. The DIN is on a "video" extension board, so as soon as I can I will hook up my oscilloscope trying to find which signal goes where, and how to feed that into a SCART plug.

As it's for a monitor, it will probably not work with a TV.

@dirkt I checked the signals, it is a 50Hz Vsync and 15.625 kHz Hsync, so it looks like PAL. What options do I have is a TV cannot handle this? What is the difference in signals? Could for example a Commodore 1084 (which is a monitor) handle this signal?

A TV normally expects both sync signals with defined levels and defined polarities mixed in the composite signal. PAL also expects a special vsync sequence between frames. Monitors can expect different sync levels and different sync polarities (but if you measured, you should know what's on the wire). Early monitor were wild west, everything is different. If the polarities and levels are correct, sometimes you can mix in the sync signals to composite using capacities as couplers in a custom cable. Modern digital TVs are often more tolerant. TL;DR: It depends.

The Commodore 1084 doesn't seem to have inputs for separate sync signals, at least from quickly reading the wikipedia article. If you have an old Multisync monitor somewhere (or know somebody else who has, to try it out), that would be the best option. Newer monitors often have trouble with low vsync like 50Hz.
